# How to set list view description with 2 lines in xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a listview which have a title and description,so I want to show description only first 2 lines (because description have more than 2 line ) and at the end of line want to show 3 dot (...)

Here is my list view-

```
<ListView x:Name="OrderView" RowHeight="70" ItemSelected="ItemTapped" BackgroundColor="#ffffff">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell Height="70">
                <ContentView Padding="10,10,10,10">
                    <StackLayout Spacing="0">
                        <Label Text="{Binding FullPathName}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Small" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" HeightRequest="20" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding Description}" TextColor="Gray" FontSize="Micro" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" HeightRequest="30"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ContentView>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If I have understand the problem, you can do that with customrenderers. Here a description [2-line-label-with-tail-truncation](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/29924/2-line-label-with-tail-truncation)

for example, iOS should be something like

```
    [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TwoLineLabel), typeof(TwoLineLabelRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.iOS
{
    public class TwoLineLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            Control.Lines = 2;
        }
    }
}
```

and the view...

```
 TwoLineLabel Heading = new TwoLineLabel()
{
        LineBreakMode = LineBreakMode.TailTruncation
};
```

for Android should be something like

```
'public class TwoLineLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
{
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs e)
{
base.OnElementChanged(e);

                if (Control != null)
                {
                    Control.LayoutChange += (s, args) =>
                    {
                        Control.Ellipsize = TextUtils.TruncateAt.End;
                        Control.SetMaxLines(2);
                    };
                }
            }
        }
```